# Two i.i.d random variables inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

If $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d positive random variables,

1. Prove that $\Bbb E(X/Y) \ge 1$: I use Jensen's inequality $\Bbb E[\exp(\log(X/Y))]$ and get the answer. One can also use the A-G inequality to prove this.
2. (Difficult) if ${\rm Var}(\log(X))\ge 2$, prove that $\Bbb E(X/Y) \ge 2$.

While the first inequality is not that difficult, the second one is rather hard...

Comment: Anybody have any idea about the second inequality? my thought is some concept like Fisher's information etc about $log(X)$

Comment: Scale $X$ so that $E(\log X)=0$. Let $V\sim \log X: EV=0,EV^2=2$. Then you need to show that $$Ee^V Ee^{-V}\ge 2$$ But $$e^V\ge 1+V+\frac 1 2V^2[V>0]$$ and $$e^{-V}\ge 1-V+\frac 1 2V^2[V<0]$$ and hence you need $$(1+\frac {E(V^2[V>0])}2)(1+\frac {E(V^2[V<0])}2)\ge 2$$ which is true since $$\frac {E(V^2[V>0])}2+\frac {E(V^2[V<0])}2=1$$ Finding a tighter lower bound would be more difficult.

Comment: In fact, by extending the expansion to higher terms: $e^V\ge 1+V+\sum_{k\ge 2}\frac{V^k}{k!}[V>0]$, we get $$Ee^VEe^{-V}\ge Ee^{|V|}-E|V|\ge 1+\frac{\sigma_V^2}2$$ while most likely the best bound is:

$$Ee^VEe^{-V}\ge \left(\frac{e^{\sigma_V}+e^{-\sigma_V}}2\right)^2\ge 1+\sigma_V^2$$

Comment: It can be shown that $\mathrm{E}(X/Y)\ge\cosh\left(\sqrt{2\mathrm{Var}(\log(X))}\,\right)$

Comment: This question was put on hold because it needs to be revised. Please include additional context: where did you encounter the problem? Why is it of interest? What have you attempted already? These things make the question more interesting and help others write more useful answers. Posts that merely state a problem without context are discouraged. You can edit the question to improve it.

Comment: The fact that this was an interview question had been given in the title, but it was removed after closure. The OP tells what they used to solve the first part; however, it seems that they have no idea how to approach the second part. If that is so, then I guess they can't add much and they are out of luck here.

Comment: @LAWRENCE: can you write down an equation relating the variance of $\log(X)$ to that of $\log(X/Y)$, and that to the expected values of $\log(X/Y)^2$ and $\log(X/Y)$? Can you compute the expected value of $\log(X/Y)$? If so, please add these things to your question and see if you can think of a way to get a bound on the expected value of $X/Y$ from that of $\log(X/Y)$ and its powers.

Comment: @robjohn Your clue is really great, and I appreciate it. I soon start to work it on my own soon.

Comment: More generally, if you are trying to minimize $Eg(X)$ subject to $Ef(X)=0$ for symmetric convex $f$ and $g$ and $\frac {g''}{g'}>\frac{f''}{f'}$ on $(0,\infty)$ (i.e. $g$ curves more than $f$), then the minimum is achieved for $X$ symmetric on $f^{-1}(0)$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I worked this when I made my comment.

---

Since $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed:
$$
\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{E}}
\begin{align}
\E(\log(X/Y))
&=\E(\log(X))-\E(\log(Y))\\
&=0
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, since $X$ and $Y$ are independent
$$
\begin{align}
\E\left(\log(X/Y)^2\right)
&=\E\left(\log(X/Y)^2\right)-\E(\log(X/Y))^2\\
&=\Var(\log(X/Y))\\
&=\Var(\log(X)-\log(Y))\\
&=\Var(\log(X))+\Var(\log(Y))\\
&=2\Var(\log(X))
\end{align}
$$
Jensen gives that for $k\ge1$,
$$
\begin{align}
\E\left(\log(X/Y)^{2k}\right)
&\ge\E\!\left(\log(X/Y)^2\right)^k\\
&=\sqrt{2\Var(\log(X))}^{\,2k}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, because $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed
$$
\begin{align}
\E(X/Y)
&=\tfrac12\left(\E(X/Y)+\E(Y/X)\right)\\[3pt]
&=\E\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{2k!}\log(X/Y)^{2k}\right)\\
&\ge\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{2k!}\sqrt{2\Var(\log(X))}^{\,2k}\\[9pt]
&=\cosh\left(\sqrt{2\Var(\log(X))}\,\right)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 2):

The second one can be proved in an analogous way. Let us write $U = \log X$ and $V = \log Y$. Then we may write

$$ \Bbb{E}[X/Y] = \Bbb{E}[e^{U-V}] = \frac{1}{2}\Bbb{E}[e^{U-V}] + \frac{1}{2}\Bbb{E}[e^{V-U}] = \Bbb{E}\cosh(U-V). $$

Now let $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n)!}z^n = \cosh\sqrt{z}$. This function is convex on $[0, \infty)$. Thus by the Jensen's inequality,

$$ \Bbb{E}\cosh(U-V) = \Bbb{E}f((U-V)^2) \geq f( \Bbb{E}[(U-V)^2] ). $$

Simplifying the last expression gives $f(2\operatorname{var}(U))$ and therefore

$$ \Bbb{E}[X/Y] \geq \cosh\sqrt{2\smash[b]{\operatorname{var}(\log X)}} $$

as **@robjohn** commented.

Comment: Didn't think of a symmetric presentation. Minimizing $E\cosh Z$ for a symmetric $Z$ with fixed $E(Z^2)$, we can easily see that $Z|Z>0$ has to be degenerate (since $\frac {(\cosh(x))'}{(x^2)'}$ is increasing for $x>0$). This implies that $U$ and $V$ are two point distributions and the minimum is achieved for symmetric ones. In other words $$Ee^VEe^{-V}\ge\cosh^2{\sigma_V}$$ is a tight bound strictly better than the one above..

Comment: Both answers got a downvote at the same time.

Comment: @robjohn Maybe the story is as simple as someone want to be mischievous... I just wonder why.